# Explain the relationship between Tikhonov regularization, SVD , least squres, and the Wiener filter

Tags: signal-analysis, filter-design, inverse-problem

I found in the
[Wikipedia site for Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)
that the SVD for a Tikhonov regularized problem take us to the least squares regularized solution:

\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{x}= V D U^T b,
\end{eqnarray}
with
\begin{eqnarray}
D_{ii} = \frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_i^2 + \alpha^2}
\end{eqnarray}
They call $f_i=D_{ii}$ the Wiener weights. Here $\sigma_i$ are the singular values and $\alpha$ is the Tikhnov regularization parameter for the Tikhonov matrix $\Gamma = \alpha I$.

I do not see any connection for the filter coefficients $f_i$ and Wiener filtering as it is done in signal processing.  Any ideas?